# After file upload: modify properties

Tags: document-library, content-type, sharepoint-rest-api, error, document-set

First: I am a noob and I use the REST API of SP server with Java, so no SDK involved here.

I uploaded a file to a Document set. Now I have to modify the ContentType and some other custom fields (properties) of the file. I used this kind of endpoint to upload it:

```
_api/web/getfolderbyserverrelativeurl(''{0}/{1}'')/files/add(overwrite=true, url=''{2}'')?$expand=ListItemAllFields
```

Where the placeholders will be replaced with:

- serverRelativeUrl
- folder name (docset title)
- file name

I get a response like this:

```
{
  "ListItemAllFields": {
    "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
    "Id": 488,
    "ServerRedirectedEmbedUri": null,
    "ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl": "",
    "ID": 488,
    "ContentTypeId": "0x0101000CAB0B3907F52E45B48A63D0764D7D4E",
    "Created": "2021-10-21T11:52:06",
    "AuthorId": 11,
    "Modified": "2021-10-21T11:52:06",
    "EditorId": 11,
    "OData__CopySource": null,
    "CheckoutUserId": null,
    "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
    "GUID": "bde8b1ba-b7dd-4797-99c7-0e4e8b3cd6ef",
    "ComplianceAssetId": null,
    "DocumentSetDescription": null,
    "TaskItId": null,
    "TaskItPriority": null,
    "TaskItComments": null,
    "TaskItStartDate": null,
    "TaskItDueDate": null,
    "TaskItInternStatus": null,
    "TaskItInternAssignToId": null,
    "TaskItInternAssignToStringId": null,
    "TaskItInternAssignCcId": [],
    "TaskItInternAssignCcStringId": [],
    "TaskItPlannedSteps": null,
    "TaskItContactNotes": null,
    "TaskItResults": null,
    "TaskItExternStatus": null,
    "TaskItExternAssignTo": null,
    "TaskItExternAssignCc": null,
    "TaskItMailSubject": null,
    "TaskItMailSender": null,
    "TaskItMailReceiver": null,
    "TaskItMailReceiptDate": "2021-10-21T11:52:06"
  },
  "CheckInComment": "",
  "CheckOutType": 2,
  "ContentTag": "{62DFBCF6-7236-4A5E-A39E-BEA836D26E92},1,1",
  "CustomizedPageStatus": 0,
  "ETag": "\"{62DFBCF6-7236-4A5E-A39E-BEA836D26E92},1\"",
  "Exists": true,
  "IrmEnabled": false,
  "Length": "2400",
  "Level": 1,
  "LinkingUri": null,
  "LinkingUrl": "",
  "MajorVersion": 1,
  "MinorVersion": 0,
  "Name": "mail ne mail mit zeug und so_f.eml",
  "ServerRelativeUrl": "/websites/A0000023/TaskItLibrary/neue Aufgabe mit Attachments/mail ne mail mit zeug und so_f.eml",
  "TimeCreated": "2021-10-21T09:52:06Z",
  "TimeLastModified": "2021-10-21T09:52:06Z",
  "Title": null,
  "UIVersion": 512,
  "UIVersionLabel": "1.0",
  "UniqueId": "62dfbcf6-7236-4a5e-a39e-bea836d26e92"
}
```

The fields starting with "TaskIt" are the custom fields I want to change and also the content type of the element itself by using a certain content type ID.

Now I am trying to modify the data using this endpoint

```
_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/websites/A0000023/TaskItLibrary/neue%20Aufgabe%20mit%20Attachments/mail%20ne%20mail%20mit%20zeug%20und%20so_f.eml')
```

Method is POST, the header contains a valid request digest etc. I am sending JSON data like this:

```
{
    "foo":"bar"
}
```

but whatever I try to modify (not "foo" of course) will result in the error which says:

> "the given parameter does not exist in the method "getfilebyserverrelativepath" " (translated from German here, so I hope you recognize this error). It's a `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException`

There must be some voodoo on how to modify a file in a Document set so I hope for a solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are getting item `ID` in response, you can update file properties using `/items` endpoint like:

```
function UpdateDocProperties(itemId) {
    var siteUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/";
    var updateDocPropertiesEndpoint = siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('DocumentSets')/items(" + itemId + ")";
    var payload = {
        "__metadata": { "type": "SP.Data.DocumentSetsItem" },
        "Title": "My custom Title"
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: updateDocPropertiesEndpoint,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),
        async: false,
        headers: {
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE",
            "If-Match": "*"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Properties updated successfully");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
UpdateDocProperties(4)
```

Where `DocumentSets` is the name of document library & `4` is item ID (show below images).

**Output**:

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Similarly, you can update your other fields by adding those to `payload` variable.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work: if I only refer to "DocumentSets" what happens to the part where the doc set is referenced? Shouldn't the URL contain this, too? Like: "getByTitle('DocumentSets')/My Document Set/items(123)" ?

Comment: Not required to pass the URL of document set. Every document (may it be inside folder/document set/or directly uploaded inside library) has unique `ID` at "document library level" >> So it is enough to pass the name of library & document item ID. I have tested above code with document sets only & it is working for me. Are you getting any error? if yes, what's the error message? Are you passing correct `__metadata` type in payload?

Comment: No worries, somehow I managed to work around my issues. I changed the URI to something like this though:
_api/Web/Lists(@v0)/Items(@v1)?&@v0=guid'f87588a7-cdfe-46ac-aefa-78dd278fdc8a'&@v1=528

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. and yes, there are multiple ways to get lists like `/Lists(<guid>)` OR `/Lists/getbytitle('<display name of list>')` OR `web/getList("/sites/dev/Lists/Addresses")`, etc.